# In a test that has multiple choice questions with four options each, when should a test-taker not pick options randomly?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let's say that a test-taker takes a test with multiple choice questions with four options. Picking the right answer 1 mark and there is a penalty of 0.25 marks (say) for picking the wrong answer. That is, so:

> Question: "What is the capital of China?"
>
> Options:
>
> A) Washington DC
> B) London
> C) Beijing
> D) Cairo

Assuming that the test taker does not know the answer to a few questions in the test, when should he or she refrain from picking random options?
If a test-taker gains 1 mark for every right answer and loses 0.25 marks for every wrong answer, then I say that they should pick random options for questions they don't know because the probability of picking the right answer is 0.25, and the marks gained is 1 -- thus the expected value is 0.25 The probability of picking the wrong answer is 0.75 and the penalty is 0.25 -- thus the expected value is .1875. Therefore by picking random answers, a test-taker would gain 0.0625 points per question.

I'd like to know if this line of thinking is correct, and, specifcally if the final expected gain (0.0625) is correct.

Comment: Suppose the taker needs 9 points to pass the class, and they are completely sure of their answers for 9/10 questions but don't know the answer to the last. Then they should not pick randomly.

Comment: But what if the taker's objective was to maximize their score? Suppose the taker knows the answer for 9/10 questions. Should they not pick the answer to the 10th question randomly? Speaking purely in terms of probability, the expected score of the test taker if they answer the 10th question randomly would be 9.0625 against the score of 9 if they don't answer it.

Comment: Your thinking and 0.0625 are correct. If you like, you can do some simulation to verify your results.